# Ссылка на обьект не указывает на экземпляр обьекта

Tags: delphi, pascal

Кто может объяснить в чем ошибка. Не всегда отрабатывает как нужно. Хелп Плииииииииииииииииз!!!!!!
Да и само задание реализовать очередь от -50 до +50 и удалить все элементы стоящие до минимального.

```
Program Ochered;

type
{Тип основных данных.}
TData = Integer;
{Тип указателя на элемент очереди.}
TPElem = ^TElem;
{Тип элемента очереди.}
TElem = record
Data : TData; {Основные данные.}
PNext : TPElem; {Указатель на следующий элемент очереди.}
end;
{Тип, определяющий очередь.}
TQueue = record
PFirst, PLast : TPElem; {Указатели на первый и на последний элементы очереди.}
end;

{Начальная инициализация очереди. Внимание! Эту процедуру можно выполнять
только в отношении пустой очереди. Иначе будут утечки памяти.
Если очередь непуста, то следует применить вызов QFree().}
procedure Init(var aQ : TQueue);
begin
aQ.PFirst := nil;
aQ.PLast := nil;
end;

{Добавление элемента в конец очереди.}
procedure Push(var aQ : TQueue; const aData : TData);
var
PElem : TPElem;
begin
New(PElem); {Выделение памяти для элемента.}
PElem^.Data := aData; {Записываем основные данные.}
PElem^.PNext := nil; {Т. к., элемент добавляется в конец очереди, то указатель на следующий элемент = NIL.}
if aQ.PFirst = nil then {Если очередь пуста, то новый элемент становится первым элементом очереди.}
aQ.PFirst := PElem
else {Если очередь непустая, то новый элемент прикрепляем к последнему элементу очереди.}
aQ.PLast^.PNext := PElem;
aQ.PLast := PElem; {Добавленный элемент становится последним элементом очереди.}
end;


procedure QWriteln(const aQ : TQueue);
var
PElem : TPElem;
begin
PElem := aQ.PFirst;
if PElem <> nil then
repeat
if PElem <> aQ.PFirst then {Если это не первый элемент очереди, то ставим перед ним запятую.}
Write(', ');
Write(PElem^.Data); {Распечатка основных данных элемента.}
PElem := PElem^.PNext; {Указатель на следующий элемент.}
until PElem = nil
else
Write('Очередь пуста.');
Writeln;
end;


function minValue(const aQ : TQueue):integer;
var
PElem : TPElem;
min : integer;
begin
PElem := aQ.PFirst;
min:= 0;
if PElem <> nil then
repeat
if PElem^.Data < min then {Если это не первый элемент очереди, то ставим перед ним запятую.}
min:= PElem^.Data; {Распечатка основных данных элемента.}
PElem := PElem^.PNext; {Указатель на следующий элемент.}
until PElem = nil;
minValue:=min;
end;



procedure delElem(var aQ : TQueue);
var
{вспомогательный указатель, помогающий произвести операцию удаления}
p : TPElem;
{начало тела процедуры}
begin
{устанавливаем вспомогательный указатель на первый элемент очереди}
p := aQ.PFirst;
{перемещаем указатель начала очереди begQ на следующий элемент (второй)}
aQ.PFirst := aQ.PFirst^.PNext;
{полностью "отвязываем" удаляемый элемент из очереди, чтобы он не имел
абсолютно никаких связей с остальными элементами очереди. Данная "отвязка"
не является обязательной, так как после удаления все связи будут
автоматически уничтожены}
p^.PNext := NIL;
{удаляем первый элемент из очереди}
dispose(p);
{конец тела процедуры}
end;

const
M = 15; {Количество элементов, которые мы добавим в очередь.}
var
Q1, Q2 : TQueue;
Data, DFind, DNew : TData;
i : Integer;
S : String;
min : integer;
begin
{Начальная инициализация очередей.}
Init(Q1);


{Добавление элементов в первую очередь.}
Randomize;
for i := 1 to M do
Push(Q1, Random(101) - 50); {Целые числа из диапазона -50..+50.}
Writeln('Составлена исходная очередь (начало - конец):');
QWriteln(Q1);
min:= minValue(Q1);

delElem(Q1);


repeat
delElem(Q1);
Q1.PFirst := Q1.PFirst^.PNext; {Указатель на следующий элемент.}
until Q1.PFirst^.Data = min;
writeln('Итоговая очередь');
QWriteln(Q1);
readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Делайте отступы в коде.
2. `Push(Q1, Random(101) - 50); {Целые числа из диапазона 0..9.}` - дальше можно не читать :).
3. *Что будет в Вашем цикле удаления, если минимальный элемент был первым или вторым?*
4. `Q1.PFirst := Q1.PFirst^.PNext;` что это за манипуляции с указателями в цикле? Для этого есть функция `delElem`.

---

```
    min := minValue(Q1);
    while (Q1.PFirst <> nil) and (Q1.PFirst^.Data <> min) do
    begin
      delElem(Q1);
    end;
```

Comment: Сори забыл исправить там от -50 до 50

Comment: И ещё пара моментов: что будет, если вызвать delElem() для пустой очереди? И что будет с указателем на последний элемент очереди, если его удалить?